# Knockout computed observable dont eval when subscribed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am creating a `ko.computedObservable` like so:

```
var holder = ko.observable();

var makeAjax = function(){
   holder('new value');
};

var result = ko.computed({
    read: function () {

      makeAjax();
      return holder();
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
        //not relevant
    },
    deferEvaluation: true
});
```

I would like to be able to `subscribe` to `result` without causing the `read` function to execute.

```
result.subscribe(function(val){
   console.log(val);
});
```

However this call to subscribe causes `read` to execute. Is there any way to subscribe without causing it to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Knockout are you using? I can't re-create this behavior. Here is a snippet I ran on [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/wimekapehu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) with KO 3.0 and running it does not cause the result read function to evaluate until you call getResult()

```
var vm = function() {

    var holder = ko.observable();

    var makeAjax = function() {
        holder('new value');
    };

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            console.log('excuting read')
            makeAjax();
            return holder();
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            console.log('setting holder to ' + newValue)
                //not relevant
            holder(newValue)
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });


    result.subscribe(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    });

    this.getResult = function() {
        return result;
    }
    this.setResult = function(val) {
        result(val);
    }
}

var VM = new vm();


ko.applyBindings(VM);

VM.setResult("test");
```

Comment: Aha, it is only occuring on knockout 3.2. Your code works perfectly in knockout 3.0, but in knockout 3.2 it behaves as I described. Going to say this is a regression in the library. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. BTW, I love the GH issue -> SO question and back to issue with comments and PR.